# How to start mysql after shutdown

Tags: mysql

In my Ubuntu VPS MYSQL suddenly stopped working When i checked the log i found the following , I'm newbie to linux , please help me in solving this, also i need all the database back without any fail

here is the log file [Mysql Error Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1zRaKD0mV1FU3V5LVNKLTRvZWs/view?usp=sharing)

please help to fix the issue

Comment: You say "after shutdown", what do you mean by "after shutdown"?  After VPS shutdown, or after the service just crashes?

Comment: i see the log that every plugins got shut down, please check the log

Answer (score 1):

In your log file have problems is:

```
2017-08-30T16:08:05.473317Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
2017-08-30T16:08:05.473738Z 0 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2017-08-30T16:08:05.473812Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2017-08-30T16:08:05.475964Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2017-08-30T16:08:05.481167Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2017-08-30T16:08:05.481328Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

With problems, You can init location mysql will solve your issue.
`mysql_install_db --user=mysql --ldata=[destination]` refer this. After you can change mysql ownership and group privileges with command:

```
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

and

`chgrp -R mysql /var/lib/mysql`

And you remember to restart mysql service after updating configurations with `service mysqld restart`

Next to set base directory and check the path by issuing commands which `mysql_install_db` and which `my_print_defaults`. Pass that path with `--basedir=/your path`. This is well explained with command:

When you run command `mysql_install_db --user=mysql --ldata=[destination]` have problems `"FATAL ERROR: Could not find ./bin/my_print_defaults"`.

You can fixed with solution look for binary path:

- Which mysql_install_db

  /usr/local/bin/mysql_install_db
- Which my_print_defaults

  /usr/local/bin/my_print_defaults